# Openshift volume mount permission errors

Tags: openshift

I am using shared volume EFS in my Openshift deployment..
The volume is showing lesser permission for group

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root 6144 Oct 21 04:33 events.

I have set supplemental group

```
  securityContext:
    supplementalGroups:
    - 5555
```

kubectl exec -it pod/app-599b696b46-hkv6b -n appr -- bash

bash-4.2$ id
uid=1000940000(1000940000) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),**5555**,1000940000

EFS access point is also set with right permission
[image]

Still I have same permission errors..any help on this is much appreciated...

Comment: What did you intend to happen?

Comment: I even tried uid 0 and gid 0 still same issue..I should not be seeing any permission errors..and the pods should be able to write into the shared volume

Comment: Assuming the NFS storage permissions are as in the right part of the image, did you try adding permissions until it works? Even if you might not use the final needed\working permissions you'd at least know the needed level. I feel this is more an EFS issue or other specific configuration issue cause I have a similar situation and the solution you tried worked there